# Is it possible to add a Magento partial payment invoice state

Tags: magento-1.7, payment, invoice, multiple

In Magento invoices can have 3 states, 
Paid,
Pending
Canceled.

Is it possible to add a 4th one, so I can set an invoice "partial paid".
This should be visible in the admin grid in Magento.

I already found this module, but this doesnt work like I want in the admin.
https://www.indiesinc.com/magento-extensions/partial-payment.html

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the customization of this extension. If you wish you can have a chat with our technical experts in order to make our extension to work as per your wish.

Comment: I have a question for your plugin , How can I integrate your partial payment option with citrus pay payment gateway. When i check out it shows full amount ,not the partial amount,For e.g I have product of 1000 at the checkout cart, using your plugin it shows 200 as the paying now and remaining amount as later but when I go to citrus payment gateway there it says 1000,How to make the payment as 200 ,Any help will be greatly appreciated thanks